# Event Based Gateway to determine the flow

Tags: activiti, bpmn, business-process-management

New in bpm. Trying to model a business flow with event based gateways for logical routing as shown in figure below. Please confirm if the approach taken is correct or nor.[image]

Comment: The core idea of BPMN is human readable diagrams. Please add some meaningful labels to your events (especially start event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the eventbased gateway here: you can simply have multiple message start events (giving them a different id) and call the runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByMessage(message) method.

A more general remark: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do here. Could you describe what you're trying to accomplish, so we can help with how this should be best modeled?